# Is testing on $L^2 \cap L^{\infty}$ sufficient?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I want to show that some operator $T:L^2  \rightarrow L^2$ is a $L^{1}$ contraction, i.e. I want to show that for all $f \in L^2 \cap L^{1}$ we have

$$\|(Tf)\|_1 \le \|f\|_1.$$

To do so, I used $g \in L^2 \cap L^\infty$ and proved

$$|\langle Tf ,g \rangle |\le \|f\|_1 \|g\|_\infty.$$

If $L^2 \cap L^\infty$ was dense in $L^\infty$, then this would show me by Hahn-Banach that $\|Tf\|_1\le \|f\|_1.$ But unfortunately this is not true. Does anybody know whether this conclusion is still valid?

Comment: Forget the functional analysis and go back to measure theory. Think about simple functions...